# Convert <DataGridTemplateColumn> properties to <DataGridTestColumn>

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

In my application I was using this code for my datagrid text boxes:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EECAT From"
                                            Width="Auto"
                                            IsReadOnly="False">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                        Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding EECAT_From, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Margin="0,2,0,2"
                                         Background="Transparent" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I recently learned about two way databinding using Linq. My original text column code would not work with two way data binding and I had to changed the text box's to code like this:

```
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EECAT_From, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="EECAT From"
                                IsReadOnly="False"
                                x:Name="txtEECAT_From" >
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

My two way binding now works but I am having a problem setting all the formatting that I originally had into the new . Is it possible to set up the missing formatting options or is it possible to use two way data binding with my original text column code?